# Looking for an R function to create a seperate txt file for each row in csv

Tags: r, csv

My dataset is a csv where each row is a news article. Since I want to run some text mining, I need to have each article in a separate txt file in one folder.

Is there a function in R to do that?
Additionally, it would be great if the file name is a column of my choice.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You request isn't hard to do but I am wondering why it is necessary.  Why do they have to be in their own txt files?

Comment: To run the VCorpus function of the tm package.

Comment: @LisaT you can do that within R - no need to save each article as a txt file on disk.

Comment: Looking at the documentation that function requires a Source object and you can use many things including data frames to create Source objects

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem to me http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in the tm package by running the DataframeSource function:

```
docs <- read.csv("newsarticles.csv",sep=";")
ds <- DataframeSource(docs)
x <- Corpus(ds)
inspect(x)
meta(x)
```